# How to get row count from EXEC() in a TSQL SPROC?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a TSQL sproc that builds a query as and executes it as follows:

```
EXEC (@sqlTop + @sqlBody + @sqlBottom)
```

@sqlTop contains something like SELECT TOP(x) col1, col2, col3...

TOP(x) will limit the rows returned, so later I want to know what the actual number of rows in the table is that match the query.

I then replace @sqlTop with something like:

```
EXEC ('SELECT @ActualNumberOfResults = COUNT(*) ' + @sqlBody)
```

I can see why this is not working, and why a value not declared error occurs, but I think it adequately describes what I'm trying to accomplish.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could instead have the dynamic query return the result as a row set, which you would then insert into a table variable (could be a temporary or ordinary table as well) using the `INSERT ... EXEC` syntax. Afterwards you can just read the saved value into a variable using `SELECT @var = ...`:

```
DECLARE @rowcount TABLE (Value int);
INSERT INTO @rowcount
EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) ' + @sqlBody);
SELECT @ActualNumberOfResults = Value FROM @rowcount;
```

Answer (score 24):

use `sp_executesql` and an `output parameter`

example

```
DECLARE @sqlBody VARCHAR(500),@TableCount INT, @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @sqlBody = 'from sysobjects'
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT @TableCount = COUNT(*) ' + @sqlBody

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TableCount INT OUTPUT', @TableCount OUTPUT

SELECT @TableCount
GO
```

Comment: More people should vote this to the top.  This avoids the entire issue of whether `exec` or `sp_executesql` modifies `@@rowcount`

Answer (score 19):

Late in the day, but I found [this method](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost487103.aspx) much simpler:

```
-- test setup
DECLARE @sqlBody nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT MyField FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyOtherField = ''x''';
DECLARE @ActualNumberOfResults int;

-- the goods
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlBody;
SET @ActualNumberOfResults = @@ROWCOUNT;
SELECT @ActualNumberOfResults;
```

Comment: [The documentation for @@ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) says that EXECUTE statements don't change @@ROWCOUNT. Is sp_executesql an exception?

Comment: @TannerSwett Interesting. I can't find an explicit reference in official documentation, but I would assume it has something to do with the differences in the way executing ad-hoc, unparameterized SQL and the sp_executesql variety are handled by the engine. See [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/18/exec-vs-sp-executesql.aspx)

Comment: Previous link has moved: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/turgays/exec-vs-sp_executesql

Answer (score 4):

After executing your actual query store the result of `@@ROWCOUNT` in any variable which you can use later.

`EXEC sp_executesql 'SELECT TOP 10 FROM ABX'`

`SET @TotRecord = @@ROWCOUNT` into your variable for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that dynamic SQL has its own scope. Any variable declared/modified there will go out of scope after your `EXEC` or your `sp_executesql`.

Suggest writing to a temp table, which will be in scope to your dynamic SQL statement, and outside.

Perhaps put it in your `sqlBottom`:

```
CREATE TABLE ##tempCounter(MyNum int);

EXEC('SELECT @ActualNumberOfResults = COUNT(*) ' + @sqlBody + 
       '; INSERT INTO ##tempCounter(MyNum) VALUES(@ActualNumberOfResults);');

SELECT MyNum FROM ##tempCounter;
```

Comment: `sp_executesql` can use output parameters, see my example

Answer (score 1):

You can use output variable in SP_EXECUTESQL

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(100) = '@ROW_SQL INT OUTPUT'
DECLARE @AFFECTED_ROWS INT;

SELECT
@SQL = N'SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2'
SELECT @SQL += 'SELECT @ROW_SQL = @@ROWCOUNT;';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @ROW_SQL=@AFFECTED_ROWS OUTPUT;

PRINT 'Number of affected rows: ' + CAST(@AFFECTED_ROWS AS VARCHAR(20));
```

Ouput:

```
SQL2.sql: Number of affected rows: 2
```

Thanks Jesus Fernandez!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the answers that create temporary tables (either using "DECLARE @rowcount TABLE" or "CREATE TABLE ##tempCounter(MyNum int)") is that you're having to read all the affected records off disk into memory. If you're expecting a large number of records this may take some time.

So if the answer is likely to be large the "use sp_executesql and an output parameter" solution is a more efficient answer. And it does appear to work.